# Разница в объявлении переменных объектом или отдельными элементами (var)

Tags: javascript

Глупый вопрос. Стоит ли объединять несколько переменных в javascript коде в объект? Будет ли разница между кучей объявленных переменных и одним объектом (оптимизация, загруженность памяти)?

```
var a = 'string',
    b = 1234545,
    c = $('.selector'),
    d = true;
```

//или

```
var mainVariables = {
    a : 'string',
    b : 1234,
    c : $('.selector')
}
```

Comment: Странный вопрос. Заморачиватся с современными реалиями о оптимизации и загруженности памяти на js. Сколько бит из 8-м гигабайт этим сэкономишь? А вот использовать переменную "а" удобнее чем "mainVariables.а".

Comment: @СтаниславУсанов спасибо, я просто думал что при при разном объявлении под переменных выделяется разный объём памяти. Но если он настолько мал тогда ладно)

Answer (score 3):

Если эти переменные имеют принадлежность к одной сущности, то стоит объединить:

```
user = {
  name: "Alex",
  age: 23
}
```

Если это разные по смыслу переменные - не стоит.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете это сами проверить в инструментах разработчика в браузере, в Chrome принцип примерно такой: заходите во вкладку memory делаете snapshot вбиваете в console свой объект делаете еще snapshot смотрите по фильтру "оbject allocated between numOfSnapshot numOfSnapshot + 1"
находите свой объект смотрите сколько памяти в байтах он занимает, проделываете тоже самое с переменными, только они уже в System/context.

---

А если вам просто интересно кто занимает памяти больше, то ответ: отдельно объявленные переменные занимают памяти больше, чем в объекте.